# Error generating a list with REST to produce JSON response

Tags: json, web-services, rest

I'm trying to consume a list with Json from Android. But, I think that I'm not generating well the list, and when I try to parse with Json I get and error.

I'm getting this result:

[{"id":7,"word":"w6","definition":"d6","language":"es","numberDefinition":0,"success":false},{"id":8,"word":"w7\n","definition":"d7","language":"es","numberDefinition":0,"success":false},{"id":9,"word":"w8","definition":"d8","language":"es","numberDefinition":0,"success":false}]

```
@GET
@Path("words")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Word> getWords(@QueryParam("number") int number  ) {
    List<Word> list = null;

    list = dictionary.getListWords(number);

    return list;
}
```

My java codein Android is:

```
            respJSON = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray lineItems = respJSON.getJSONArray("words");
            listWords = new ArrayList<Word>();

            for(int i=0; i<lineItems.length(); i++)
            {               
                JSONObject obj = lineItems.getJSONObject(i);                
                id = obj.getInt(ConstantsTrivial.WORD_ID);
                definition = obj.getString(ConstantsTrivial.WORD_DEFINITION);
                language = obj.getString(ConstantsTrivial.WORD_LANGUAGE);
                wordName = obj.getString(ConstantsTrivial.WORD_NAME);
                numberDefinition = obj.getInt(ConstantsTrivial.WORD_NUMBER_DEFINITION);
                word = new Word(id, wordName, definition, language, numberDefinition);

                listWords.add(word);
            }
```

I'm looking for a "words",, I know this mistake, but I dont know what I should do so that my webservice generate the list on the right way..

The error is:

03-19 13:09:48.086: E/WebServiceTask(9868): Value [{"numberDefinition":0,"id":1,"word":"w0","language":"ES","definition":"d0","success":false},{"numberDefinition":0,"id":3,"word":"w2","language":"es","definition":"d2","success":false},{"numberDefinition":0,"id":4,"word":"w3","language":"es","definition":"d3","success":false},{"numberDefinition":0,"id":9,"word":"w8","language":"es","definition":"d8","success":false}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in the first line of your code. Your value is a JSONArray, not a JSONObject. The line should be:

```
JSONArray lineItems = new JSONArray(response);
```

And don't forget to delete the second line.

Comment: Thank you, What I don't know if how I'd generate a list kind of:

Comment: Here is how to build a collection from a JSONArray: https://github.com/Hypertopic/Porphyry/blob/master/src/org/json/JSONArray.java#L952